# WSO2 XACML dynamic attribute value

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, alfa

I wanted to write XACML in Wso2 Identity server where i want to authorize user to access country page if user belongs to that country http://localhost:8080/Country_name.

```
User Country
1   India
2   US
3   UK
4   Australia
```

And user country mapping is added from UI (of Web application).Now if user 2 logins it should not be able to access other country page other than US

Thanks
Priyanka Goel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are saying you are trying to get access to a page and that page belongs to a country. You are saying:

- A user can view a page if the user belongs to the same country as the page.

If this is indeed correct, the authorization policy is very simple. Here is what it would look like using [ALFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALFA_(XACML)):

```
 /**
  * Control access to webpage
  */
 policy accessPage{
     target clause action_id == "view" and com.axiomatics.examples.objectType == "page"
     apply firstApplicable
     /**
      * Users can view a page if they are in the same country
      */
     rule allowSameCountry{
         permit
         condition user.country == page.country
     }
 }
```

In [XACML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XACML) (XML) it looks like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!--This file was generated by the ALFA Plugin for Eclipse from Axiomatics AB (http://www.axiomatics.com). 
 Any modification to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source ALFA file-->
<xacml3:Policy xmlns:xacml3="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"
    PolicyId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/so.accessPage"
    RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable"
    Version="1.0">
    <xacml3:Description>Control access to webpage</xacml3:Description>
    <xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
        <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116</xacml3:XPathVersion>
    </xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
    <xacml3:Target>
        <xacml3:AnyOf>
            <xacml3:AllOf>
                <xacml3:Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                    <xacml3:AttributeValue
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">view</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                    <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                        AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id"
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action"
                        MustBePresent="false"
                    />
                </xacml3:Match>
                <xacml3:Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                    <xacml3:AttributeValue
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">page</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                    <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                        AttributeId="com.axiomatics.examples.objectType"
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"
                        MustBePresent="false"
                    />
                </xacml3:Match>
            </xacml3:AllOf>
        </xacml3:AnyOf>
    </xacml3:Target>
    <xacml3:Rule 
            Effect="Permit"
            RuleId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/so.accessPage.allowSameCountry">
        <xacml3:Description>Users can view a page if they are in the same country</xacml3:Description>
        <xacml3:Target />
        <xacml3:Condition>
            <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of-any">
                <xacml3:Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"/>
                <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                    AttributeId="com.axiomatics.examples.user.country"
                    DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"
                    MustBePresent="false"
                />
                <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                    AttributeId="com.axiomatics.examples.page.country"
                    DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"
                    MustBePresent="false"
                />
            </xacml3:Apply>
        </xacml3:Condition>
    </xacml3:Rule>
</xacml3:Policy>
```

Comment: Thanks but I have two doubts...1. Isn't it mandatory to give attribute value?In conditions you haven't any value. 2. How to create custom attribute id in wso2.

Comment: No you don't need to use a value in the policy

Comment: Thanks. I need to read more about XACML3 but it has helped me alot. Also please correct me if i understood correctly or not that we can  use XACML to validate rule against dynamic value as well as we can create custom attribute like "com.axiomatics.examples.page.country"

Comment: yes you can use dynamic values e.g. user.country==page.country or static values e.g. user.country=="Iceland". And you can definitely create your own attributes.

Comment: Testing policy with REST API  'curl --request POST --url https://localhost:9443/api/identity/entitlement/decision/by-attrib --header 'accept: application/json' --header 'authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' --header 'content-type: application/json' --data '{"action":"read","resource":"http://localhost:9000/country","subject" : "Bob"}' -k' . Still not sure how to pass value of country as value is json web request . One of the approaches I think is Xpath but then  either web request sends data in xml or server code should change json request to XML request. Kindly suggests.

Comment: AttributeId="com.axiomatics.examples.page.country". How XACML fetch data for this attribute. URL/Resource: http://localhost:9000/accounts action :read , subject User 2. In my scenario  UI sends json to server which has country parameter and attribute value should be this country parameter or attribute Id should fetch value as this country parameter. Please let me know how to handle this scenario.